# Can't catch connection and disconnection via Socket.io with Express app

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to catch connection and disconnection from socket.io:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const port = 8080;
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
const io = new Server(server);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);

app.get('/', function (req, res){

});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log("User has connected");
  socket.on('disconnect',function(res){
    console.log("User has disconnected");
  });
});
```

I can never see the logs of "User has connected" or "User has disconnected" while browsing to http://localhost:8080

Comment: in app.get I connect to mongo and send html file to the client and it works well, I just didn't want it to look messy here.

Answer (score 0):

The connection event is raised when the socket.io client has connected, not the HTTP client.

In your case you don't have a socket.io client at all.

Consider sending a HTML file which initializes a socket.io client.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "abc.html"));
});
```

and have these script tags in abc.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");
</script>
```